# how to get the traceback of failed test (unittest) in the tearDown() function

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, logging, python-unittest

I want to save all the traceback of all the exceptions from every failed test I run to an external file.
Instead of using try and except in every test i would like to use the tearDown of unittest so it will be more generic.

something like:

```
import traceback
import unittest

class SomeTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_some_test(self):
        self.assertTrue(False)

    def tearDown(self):
        with open(logger.txt, 'a') as doc:
            doc.write(traceback.format_exc())
```

the problem is that the exception that you get in the test_some_test cant be called with traceback in the teardown (the tracebacke return None)

any suggestion?

Comment: All exceptions are *already* recorded, on the `TestResult`; see [`TestResult.addFailure()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestResult.addFailure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after I went over a big piece of the unittest code I found a solution!

The `TestCase` class has an `_outcome` attribute.
The `_outcome` has a list type attribute called `errors`.
`errors[0][1]` is a tuple that is exactly like the `sys.exc_info()` output that contains the traceback.
So now that I have this tuple that I can use in `traceback.format_exception()` just like `traceback.format_exc()` uses it and **problem solved**.

```
def tearDown(self):
    try:
        etype, value, tb = self._outcome.errors[0][1]
        trace = ''.join(traceback.format_exception(etype=etype, value=value, tb=tb, limit=None))
        date = '{date}\n'.format(date=str(datetime.datetime.now()))
        name = '\n' + self._testMethodName + '-\n'
        with open(self.logger, 'a') as doc:
            doc.write(name + date + trace)
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Yes, `_outcome` is the current `TestResult` instance.

Comment: Personally, I'd handle this at the runner level however.